# Hi.I want to use same menu in different pages in xaml.how to do it?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have two pages in xaml.in first page(MainWindow.xaml),i create menu.In second page i want to use menu again.

Questions:

- How i do this?

Comment: It's good practice to show the code you already tried if you post questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 good option would be to put the menu into a UserControl that can be used on both pages.

Here is a reasonably good tutorial on this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/user-control-in-wpf/